# One click show/hide sticky notes ubuntu 14.04 gnome flashback

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, stickynotes

On Ubuntu 12.04 I used this "sticky notes" application:

```
Sticky Notes 3.4.1
Sticky Notes for the GNOME Desktop Environment
© 2002-2003 Loban A Rahman, © 2005 Davyd Madeley
```

which was very handy to use: Left click on indicator applet to show/hide all notes. Right click open menu.

Now in Ubuntu 14.04 I installed `indicator-stickynotes 0.4.2-0~ppa2` which has different, and in my opinion much less handy behaviour.

Left click on the icon open a context menu. Then **I have to click once more** on *show all* or *hide all* notes.

This one click makes the usage 100% slower, because of which I almost don't use it (while the older version with one-click I used a lot)

I'm not sure if this `indicator-stickynotes 0.4.2-0~ppa2` is the new version of the sticky notes I was using in Ubutnu 12.04. If so, I don't understand why they changed the behaviour to be slower to use.

Is there any alternative (like another note making application) which has the behaviour of the original sticky notes with just one click to show/hide?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNOME desktop in Ubuntu, you can use the Extension called **Sticky Notes View**, which I find very handy.

If you have installed a GNOME shell and GNOME Tweak Tool, as well as `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, **Sticky Notes View** will be available inside `**Extensions** option in GNOME Tweak Tool. Just mark it on. Also to get your Notes you just need to do <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and to get back the working desktop, <kbd>Super</kbd>. Try this if you are a GNOME user.

Answer (score 1):

In Gnome it is possible to activate the **sticky notes** applet by doing

**<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right-click > Add to panel > sticky notes**

This is exactly the app I was looking for

UPDATE : in current Gnome Flashback in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS there is new version of sticky notes which lack the functionality which I need (e.g. content of notes is lost each restart, and it does not show-and-hide on one click)